# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elliptic\EC' not found

Tags: php, private-key, public-key, elliptic-curve, generate

I want to generate private/public keys using  Elliptic Curve Cryptography in PHP.

I have used this library: https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php

my code:

```
<?php
use Elliptic\EC;

// Create and initialize EC context
// (better do it once and reuse it)
$ec = new EC('secp256k1');

// Generate keys
$key = $ec->genKeyPair();

$publicKey = $key->getPublic('hex');
$privateKey = $key->getPrivate('hex');

// Print the keys to the console

echo "The address1 is {$publicKey}. \r\n";
echo "The address1 is {$privateKey}. \r\n";
```

but it shows me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Elliptic\EC' not found in /home/istabraq/bctest/test1/keygenerator.php:6
```

I have installed composer `Composer 1.6.3`
 from this tutorial:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-18-04/

then installed `sudo apt-get install php7.2-gmp`
and installed  `composer require simplito/elliptic-php` and finally installed `composer require simplito/bn-php` but the last command line shows me this output:

```
Using version ^1.1 for simplito/bn-php
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

what I have missed please help? I search for problem but did not have tutorial.

Comment: did you include the `vendor/autoload.php` file?

Comment: Hi, interesting, it might be an outdated version, perhaps this would be of interest https://github.com/simplito/elliptic-php/pull/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try include file with class or if exists `vendor/autoload.php` include it, for example:

```
<?php

include 'path/vendor/autoload.php'; //or 'path/file/EC.php'

use Elliptic\EC;

// Create and initialize EC context
// (better do it once and reuse it)
$ec = new EC('secp256k1');

// Generate keys
$key = $ec->genKeyPair();

$publicKey = $key->getPublic('hex');
$privateKey = $key->getPrivate('hex');

// Print the keys to the console

echo "The address1 is {$publicKey}. \r\n";
echo "The address1 is {$privateKey}. \r\n";
```